# How to calculate Probability with combination pr

Tags: combinations, probability

4 different written driving tests are administered by the Motor Vehicles Division.  One of these four tests is selected at random for each applicant for a driver's license.  If a group consisting of two women and three men apply for license, what is the probability that:

a. Exactly two of the five will take the same test? show all work
b. The two women will take the same test.  show all work